# <div> moving out of parent without any offset/margin set

Tags: html, css

I want something like this:

[image]

*nested folder path*

So, I copied and pasted some code from the Feeder chrome extension where I saw it and mixed it with my own to get the required thing:

```css
.folder-path {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 50px;
    width: 350px;
    border: 0.1px solid black;    
}

.folder-path .path-part {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 50px;
    line-height: 50px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    position: relative;/*HACK HERE*/
    top: -7px;
}

.folder-path .path-part + div {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 50px;
    width: 35px;
    display: inline-block;
    content: "";
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
    width: 35px;
    height: 35px;
    border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    -webkit-mask-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right bottom, from(transparent), color-stop(0.5,transparent), color-stop(0.5, #000000), to(#000000));
    position: relative;
    left: -15px; /*to move slightly left*/
    top: 6px; /*to accommodate rotation*/
}
```

```html
<div class="folder-path">
 <!--div.path-part+div-->
 <div class="path-part">Snippets</div>
    <div></div>
    
    <div class="path-part">d</div>
    <div></div>
</div>
```

However, on careful notice you will find that I had to use `position: relative` and `top`/`left` offset hacks in `.folder-path .path-part` rule. Without them, this is what it looks like:

```css
.folder-path {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 50px;
    width: 350px;
    border: 0.1px solid black;    
}

.folder-path .path-part {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 50px;
    line-height: 50px;
    position: relative;
    margin-left: 10px;
}

.folder-path .path-part + div {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 50px;
    width: 35px;
    display: inline-block;
    content: "";
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
    width: 35px;
    height: 35px;
    border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    -webkit-mask-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right bottom, from(transparent), color-stop(0.5,transparent), color-stop(0.5, #000000), to(#000000));
    position: relative;
    left: -15px; /*to move slightly left*/
    top: 6px; /*to accommodate rotation*/
}
```

```html
<div class="folder-path">
 <!--div.path-part+div-->
 <div class="path-part">Snippets</div>
    <div></div>
    
    <div class="path-part">d</div>
    <div></div>
</div>
```

As you can see, the `.path-part` has gone down a bit, without my putting any top/down padding/margin/offset properties on either itself or its parent.

[image]

*notice how the `.path-part` div has gone down a bit*

I want to know why this is happening. Thank you!

**UPDATE:** So, I got to know that this is happening because the arrows are relatively positioned. Indeed it is correct. So, I want to know if there's any way to position the arrows the way they should be without affecting the other `.path-part` divs.

Comment: It's because of the arrows which you have, since it's relatively positioned doing any change to the arrow's position affects the other `div` elements as well. You can test it out by making the arrow's as absolutely positioned and you will see that the text gets vertically aligned.

Comment: @Sahil Thank you! Please see updated question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The odd alignment is due to the default `vertical-align: baseline`. It seems you want `vertical-align: middle`

```css
.folder-path > div {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```css
.folder-path {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 50px;
  width: 350px;
  border: 0.1px solid black;    
}
.folder-path .path-part {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  height: 50px;
  line-height: 50px;
  margin-left: 10px;
}
.folder-path .path-part + div {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  height: 50px;
  width: 35px;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  width: 35px;
  height: 35px;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  -webkit-mask-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right bottom, from(transparent), color-stop(0.5,transparent), color-stop(0.5, #000000), to(#000000));
}
```

```html
<div class="folder-path">
  <!--div.path-part+div-->
  <div class="path-part">Snippets</div>
  <div></div>
  
  <div class="path-part">d</div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer!